# What should a Site Administrator/Owner understand before being being designated as such?

Tags: administration, training, governance

I was building a collection of requirements a Site Collection Administrator/Site Owner in SharePoint should have before being "turned loose" on their Site Collection.  So Far I've come up with:

Have a very solid understanding of the purpose of SharePoint and their organization's mission in implementing the SharePoint Intranet

Reasonable understanding of basic SharePoint terminology, when asked must be able to define:Web Application,Site Collection,Sub-Site,Web Part,List,Etc…

Have a working understanding of SharePoint governance at their organization, be able to understand how it applies to them in day-to day site management.

Have a working understanding of the Organization Site Architecture.  Be able to understand how they are allowed to expand on the site architecture at their department level

Have a good understanding of most SharePoint “out of the box” features, with emphasis on:
Document Libraries,Lists,Blogs,Calendars,Announcements,Web Parts (implementing),Content Editor Web Part,Etc. (Be able to find a component and implement in general, advanced concepts like Forms aren’t a major concern)

Know how to create sites (including Blogs) underneath their own site, and know when it is appropriate (referencing Site Architecture) to create a site

Know how to use Permissions, understanding inheritance

Know where to go for further information, this includes:
The roles IT and other departments play in SharePoint and who/when to go to for help

Other useful external sites (SharePoint Stackexchange, etc.)

Was curious what other SharePoint people have trained for in their Site Administration as well.  Anything vital that you think was missed?  I understand that this is probably different for every organization but there are probably some common threads.  What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Site Collection Administrator and Site Owner are really two very different roles.  The SCA is more of a technical role and has the ability to dramatically change the way the whole site operates, including enabling/disabling features and so forth.  The Site Owner is typically content focused and is more comparable to a Power User as they can only use the features enabled on the site by the SCA and cannot make substantial changes to site structure or behavior.  Of the two, the SCA would need the all of the information you list whereas a Site Owner would only need to know about a third of it.

That said, I would strongly emphasize the requirement of truly understanding permissions and inheritance.  That topic alone can cause more headaches than almost everything else combined!

I would also add:

- SharePoint Auditing as the question of Who did What
  and When seems to come up much more frequently than you might
  suspect
- Understanding the different Recycle Bins
- Basic list options like versioning, approvals, per-item visibility, basic workflows,
  incoming email, alerts, etc..

Comment: Good points!  I should probably clarify their role would be a Site Administrator in my final checklist.  Was trying to make it multi-functional though as some may later just be designated as owners.  Some overlap in responsibility granted, but plenty of differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

For both position types:

- proven and demonstrated ethical decision making
- proven level of communication required for user support and management interactions
- experience with production support, user support, systems support
- good working knowledge of the organisation's helpdesk / servicedesk / ITSM systems to manage and redirect support tickets
- good understanding and application of incident escalation
- good problem solving ability; this can be learned from problem solving courses such as KT or by constant exposure to real world incidents
- good documentation skills with a demonstrated willingness to create and improve documentation
- incident management and problem management skills
- demonstrated willingness to help and mentor others
- ability to document incidents/problems/requests for engaging higher level help including tracking progress and monitoring issues